# Unavailable Objective C selectors with scalar return values

Tags: objective-c

In the past, when I've had to compile something on Snow Leopard (or any older Mac OS X) and use some @selector that's available on Lion and higher, I've done something like this:

```
if([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(awesomeLionSelector)]) {
    [foo awesomeLionSelector]
}
```

And this has worked great. So, now I'm trying to do the same thing for a new method that returns a float, but the following line:

```
float f = [foo awesomeLionSelectorWhichReturnsFloat];
```

throws a compile error: "cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'float' in assignment". This is because the compiler doesn't know about the method and has to assume a return type of 'id'.

What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: What happens with a simple cast `float f = (float)[foo awesomeLionSelectorWhichReturnsFloat];`?

Comment: Practically the same error: invalid cast from type 'objc_object*' to type 'float'

Comment: @rishi wouldn't that break the code for Lion?

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's what I thought.

Comment: Yep, float f = [f1 floatValue]; will crash at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: according to John Caswell comment, the correct runtime function to use is `objc_msgSend_fpret()`, which returns a double.

I think you should try your way with: [objc_msgSend_stret()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/objc_msgSend_stret):

> objc_msgSend_stret
>
> Sends a message with a data-structure return value to an instance of a class.
>
> ```
>   void objc_msgSend_stret(void * stretAddr, id theReceiver, SEL theSelector,  ...)
> ```

Something like:

```
objc_msgSend_stret(&myFloatReturnValue, foo, @selector(awesomeLionSelector));
```

Comment: The method doesn't return a `struct`; if you're going to go this route the correct function is [`objc_msgSend_fpret()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW50) and you use the direct return value.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant fix, but a fix none the less.

```
#ifdef SnowLeopard
float f = [foo awesomeLionSelectorWhichReturnsFloat];
#endif
```